# How can I get this function to be called a specific amount of times?

Tags: javascript

I would like to call a function a specific amount of times. I would like the number of times I would like my function to be called in an array as seen below. I have a for loop that goes through the array and I am attempting to call the function named "thefunction"
as many times as the number in the array item. So the first item in the array is 8, so I first want "thefunction" function to be called 8 times which means I should see the alert message "thefunction" will display, 8 times and then 2 times as 2 is the next item in the array then 15 times. I'd also like to pause for a moment in between each set of calls. So after the function is called 8 times, it will pause for a moment before calling the function 2 times then again before it calls the function 15 times and on and on. Here is my code so far.

```
var thearray = ['8','2','15'];

for(j=0;  j < thearray.length; j++){ 
num = thearray[j]; 
var counter = 1;

(function foo() {
    thefunction();// function I'm calling

    if (counter < num) {
        counter++;
        setTimeout(foo, 400);
    }
})();    
} 

function thefunction (){
alert('test');
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `for` loop with the variable `j` and use an asynchronous `setTimeout()`.  The `for` loop will run to completion and the `j` variables will have already increased before the `setTimeout()` runs.  This is a classic problem with trying to use a `for` loop index from an asynchronous function.

I don't understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish so I'm not sure exactly what code to suggest.  You have three values.  Are you trying to do two loops, one to go through the array and one to process each array value?  Can you explain better what the final output should be?

---

I'm guessing here, but if what you're trying to do is to call your function 8 times, then pause, then 2 times then pause, then 15 times, then be done, you can do this:

```
function runArray(arr, fn) {
   // initialize array index - can't use for loop here with async
   var index = 0;

   function next() {
       var cnt = +arr[index];
       for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
           fn(index, cnt);
       }
       // increment array index and see if there's more to do
       ++index;
       if (index < arr.length) {
           setTimeout(next, 400);
       }
   }
   // start the whole process if the array isn't empty
   if (arr.length) {
       next();
   }
}

var theArray = ['8','2','15'];
runArray(theArray, thefunction);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Loycmb3b/

FYI, if what you're putting in the array are meant to be used as numbers, it's better to put them in the array as numbers, not as strings.  I've made my code work either way, but it's more efficient and just better code to use numbers when you mean numbers.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want thearray to be used to define how many times the function is called as many times as I'd like. So if thearray only has one item and that item is the number 10, then the function will be called 10 times. If I push another number to the array like 8, so I have 10, and 8, then the function is called 10 times, then pauses, then 8 times.

Comment: @Brandon - That's what my function does.  Did you try it?